# How to toggle the state of an item inside a map funtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a tag selection, the problem is, I don't know how to make a state for each item in the map, right now I have just one state, that, of course, will change all items.

That's the state and the function to toggle the state

```js
const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] = useState(false);

const toggleSelectedActivity = () => {
  setSelectedActivity(!selectedActivity);
};
```

and that's the map function

```js
<View style={styles.tags}>
  {activitiesObject.map((data, i) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={data.activity}
      onPress={() => toggleSelectedActivity(i)}
    >
      <Text style={selectedActivity ? styles.selectedTag : styles.tagsText}>
        {data.activity}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
</View>;
```

the image below shows what I expect to happen every time the user selects a tag

[image]

**Here is the full code:** https://snack.expo.io/KIiRsDPQv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of following options

1. change state to an array

```
const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] = useState(Array.from({ length: activitiesObject.length }, _ => false))

const toggleSelectedActivity = (index) => 
        setSelectedActivity(prev => prev.map((bool, i) => i == index ? !bool : bool))
```

while passing the index to function, and use `selectedActivity[i] ? ...`

2. extract

```
 <TouchableOpacity key={data.activity} onPress={() => toggleSelectedActivity(i)}>
          <Text style={selectedActivity ? styles.selectedTag : styles.tagsText}>{data.activity}</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

to its own component, and inside it declare the state

```
{activitiesObject.map((data, i) => <MyComp data={data} i={i} />

const MyComp = ({ data, i }) => {
  const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] = useState(false)
  return  <TouchableOpacity key={data.activity} onPress={() => setSelectedActivity(prev => !prev)}>
            <Text style={selectedActivity ? styles.selectedTag : styles.tagsText}>{data.activity}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
}
```

Comment: brilliant! Thank you

Comment: Sorry to ask a question, I'm very interest in array usestate, but I try to post your code in his link to cover the change, always shows `Unexpected token, expected ","`  is there I need to notice?

Comment: @高鵬翔 you are right mate, I forgot  one `)` at `toggleSelectedActivity `, editing my answer

Comment: @Hagai Harari I'm here trying to figure out how the funcion toggleSelectedActivity works, it's not beeing used anyware, this is magic to me, can you explain it?

Comment: @jarwin I suggested two options, in the first one (with the array) I didn't change `TouchableOpacity` `onPress`  `toggleSelectedActivity` usage, and in the second option it is not been used at all

Comment: Yep @jarwin thanks, that's an another method
@HagaiHarari I found it in the same time, it says need "," and I'm so confused, after compare jarinn's new link, finally find out it should add a `)`  lol  Thanks a lot .

Comment: @Hagai Harari  That's another way to do it Array(activitiesObject.length).fill(false)

Comment: I have add this in bookmark, It's very useful both your method, `.fill()` is magic to me, too. lol

Comment: @jarwin I prefer avoid using `.fill` cause `.fill` make all slots points at same place in memory, while `_ =>` generate a unique place in memory for each. You are right that in this specific case that it inside `useState` it bit irrelevant, but still.. and actually it way out of topic so we might stop here or continue in chat

Comment: @Hagai Harari That's useful info, my final thank you ;)

Comment: For the second method , the boolean state is mapped with similar variable name. May I know how they recognize their own state ? I a bit confuse here. Will it trigger change on the other `selectedActivity` as well?

Comment: I had included my useState declaration into the map function. It's work for what I'm doing. Just I not really sure on how does it happen haha

Comment: They don't need to recognize its own component, as the state live just in the specific component...