# Array of useState in React Native

Tags: react-native

Good day guys , I'm trying to make an array of button to open up their own modal. Each of this modal is trigger to open based on a boolean variable. Hence , this boolean variable will be an array of boolean state. Which mean each of this button in the array have their own boolean state. So I wondering, is it possible to create an array of state ? Or else If I just have 1 boolean state and if the boolean is true then all the modal will be visible and stack with each other. If it is possible, how do I do it ?

Comment: Hi, I have seen [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708842/how-to-toggle-the-state-of-an-item-inside-a-map-funtion) before, hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help , I will check it out and update the answer here.