# onClick triggering all sub menus instead of only the clicked one

Tags: reactjs

When I click on an item it should expend some sub items. This is working but if I have two, three or four etc. list items then when I click on one it expands ALL of the sub items for all the list items which is obviously not what I want. How can I fix this code to make it only open expand the one I actually clicked on?

```
const [sideActive, setSideActive] = useState(false);
  const toggleSideActive = () => {
    setSideActive(!sideActive);
  };
```

html:

```
        <li>
          <div
            onClick={toggleSideActive}
            className={
              sideActive
                ? `${styles.navList__subheading} row ${styles.row__align_v_center} ${styles.navList__subheading__open}`
                : `${styles.navList__subheading} row ${styles.row__align_v_center}`
            }
          >
            <span className={styles.navList__subheading_icon}>
              <FaBriefcaseMedical />
            </span>
            <span className={styles.navList__subheading_title}>
              insurance
            </span>
          </div>
          <ul
            className={
              sideActive
                ? `${styles.subList}`
                : `${styles.subList} ${styles.subList__hidden}`
            }
          >
            <li className={styles.subList__item}>medical</li>
            <li className={styles.subList__item}>medical</li>
            <li className={styles.subList__item}>medical</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708842/how-to-toggle-the-state-of-an-item-inside-a-map-funtion/62708922#62708922

Comment: I am not inside a map function, I am listing a sidebar menu which is not dynamic

Comment: he main thing is that the same one boolean state controls all items/

find how in your specific use case, connect each `li` to its own boolean controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a local state for tracking the selected id and show the content based on the state. Also, update the selected Id on click of the tab like below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

  const data = [
    {
      id: 1001,
      name: "Tab - 1",
      content: ["test1", "test2"]
    },
    {
      id: 1002,
      name: "Tab - 2",
      content: ["test21", "test22"]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul class="parent">
        {data.map((v) => (
          <li onClick={() => setSelected(selected !== v.id ? v.id : "")}>
            {v.name}
            {selected === v.id && (
              <ul class="content">
                {v.content.map((val) => (
                  <li>{val}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For the below example, click on the tab to see the content.

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/long-leaf-cl4cy?file=/src/App.js:0-759

Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works except when you click on an expanded item it doesn't close. It should open when you click on it and close when you click on it again

Comment: I have already included this scenario in the code base. Please check and let me know

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! One last question, I see that when I have one open and click on another, it closes the other one. Is it not possible to have multiple open at once?

Comment: yeah for that we have to track the selected tab id for each tab and status whether it is open or not.